# Foursquare - get a venue info with out outh

Tags: foursquare

I want to retrieve info from a venue without outh. But I keep getting a 400 error

```
url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/"+venue_ID+ 
    "&client_id="+clientID+
    "&client_secret="+clientSecret+
    "&v="+clientVersion;
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the fully constructed URL?

Answer (score 0):

The first "&" should actually be a "?". You should have something like:

```
url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/"+venue_ID+  
"?client_id="+clientID+
"&client_secret="+clientSecret+
"&v="+clientVersion;
```